# ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range in simple gcc program

Tags: gcc, linker, clang

related to ["ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range" on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608151/ld-32-bit-rip-relative-reference-out-of-range-on-mac-osx) but not solved and in a more complex context.  the relevant computer(s) have >32GB of RAM.

```
static const int K=1024;
static const int M=K*K;
static const int G=K*M;

const int MC = G;

void donada(float *rvec, const int MC) { rvec[MC-1]= 1.0; return; }

float notused[1][MC]; // 4GB, ramp up with first index
float used[MC]; // 4GB

int main() {
  donada( used, MC );
  donada( notused[1], MC );
}
```

and `gcc -Wall -o test test.cc`.  compiling this program not on osx yields

> ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range (4294967395 max is
>   +/-2GB): from _main (0x100000F92) to _used (0x200001000) in '_main' from /var/folders/yl/8gp3pgbn1l562ywg_q86rk6800\ 00z9/T/test-b3bebf.o
>   for architecture x86_64

on linux, there is a similar error

> test.cc:(.text+0x18): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `used' defined in .bss section in /tmp/ccqcNh2C.o

I first thought compiler flag `-Os` would fix this, but it does not.  It would be appropriate for gcc or clang to provide a more suggestive error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the relevant computer(s) have >32GB of RAM.

That's actually not very relevant. The issue is that 64-bit GCC defaults to `-mcmodel=small`, and you are trying to access data that is 4GiB away from its base symbol, which is not comatible with the small model.

From [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options):

```
-mcmodel=small
Generate code for the small code model: the program and its symbols
must be linked in the lower 2 GB of the address space. Pointers are 64 bits.
Programs can be statically or dynamically linked. This is the default code model. 

-mcmodel=medium
Generate code for the medium model: The program is linked in the lower 2 GB
of the address space. Small symbols are also placed there.
Symbols with sizes larger than -mlarge-data-threshold are put into large data
or bss sections and can be located above 2GB. 
Programs can be statically or dynamically linked.

-mcmodel=large
Generate code for the large model: This model makes no assumptions about addresses
and sizes of sections.
```

To correctly link your program, you need to use `-mcmodel=large`.

However note that this is not well tested (almost nobody does that), and that *all* code you (statically) link into your program will need to be built that way.

It is probably much better to dynamically allocate your arrays instead.

> I first thought compiler flag `-Os` would fix this

It can't: `-Os` minimizes *code* size. Your program is that you are forcing the compiler to allocate very large contiguous *data* array. There is nothing the compiler could optimize for size there.

Comment: in more complex code, it then complains `ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _...`